# Невозможно подключиться к серверу MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, openserver

Полный новичок. Следую инструкциям с этого сайта: https://ipipe.ru/info/ustanovka-wordpress-na-openserver.
Когда запускаю phpMyAdmin через OpenServer и ввожу логин root без пароля выводит ошибку:

`Невозможно подключиться к серверу MySQL`
`mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`
Что делать?

Comment: Пробуйте:
Логин: mysql
Пароль: mysql
Либо 
Логин: admin
Пароль: admin

Comment: @MiMEKiZ Спасибо! Сработало Логин: mysql Пароль: mysql

Comment: у меня тоже такая же проблема...пробывала все пароли и логины,что писали выше,всё равно не заходит.(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно ввести логин: mysql и пароль: mysql

Answer (score 0):

Логин: root
Пароль: root
и все нормально заходит